# Feller condition and Chebyshev inequality

Tags: inequality, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

So according to https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1756450. Feller condition of the CIR process can be proven by such a way (it is quite short (2 pages)). But towards the ending of the proof, I am sort of got lost. Suppose that $r(t)$ is a CIR process. From page 2 of the paper (at the Gronwall inequality), we get it inequality as
\begin{equation}
E(r^{-m} (\tau_\varepsilon \land t)) \leq r^{-m}(0) exp(mkt)
\end{equation}
What the point of the above inequality? Then how do I apply the Chebyshev inequality to get the following inequality (last equation of page 2)
\begin{equation}
P(r^{-m}(\tau_\varepsilon) \geq \varepsilon^{-m}) \leq \varepsilon^m r^{-m}(0) exp(mt)
\end{equation}
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like $k$ has been dropped from the exponent.  This may be an error in the paper.  (By the way, you have a typo also: $n$ should be $m$.)

Comment: Ah I am sorry. If it's with the $exp(k)$ . Do you think you can give an explanation to my question?

Comment: If the $k$ is there, then this is literally exactly Chebyshev's inequality (in the form sometimes also called Markov's inequality): that $P(X \ge a) \le E[X]/a$.  Here we take $X = r^{-m}(\tau_\epsilon)$ and $a = \epsilon^{-m}$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks a lot on the Markov's inequality pointer :)

Comment: @NateEldredge I have a question again... so by using Markov's inequality, we get that $P(r^{-m}(\tau_\varepsilon)\geq \varepsilon^{-m}) \leq \varepsilon^m E(r^{-m} ( \tau_\varepsilon))$ . But according to the statement of the Gronwall inequality, it gives  $E(r^{-m}(\tau_\varepsilon \land t))$ which is different from $E(r^{-m} ( \tau_\varepsilon))$.

Comment: Oh i got it, just change the $P(\tau_\epsilon \leq t)$ to $P(\tau_\epsilon \land t < t)$